# Windows 10: Disable asterisk sound when triggered from specific application

Tags: windows, system-sounds

Windows 10 has an asterisk sound, which can be triggered by applications. I know how to disable the sound altogether, but I'm trying to disable the sound when it is coming from a specific application. Is this possible?

I could of course try to configure the application itself to not trigger the sound, but I'm wondering if this is possible from the OS itself.

Comment: Short answer: No. You need to modify or configure the application to not produce a particular sound.

Comment: Good answer, why did you post it as a comment and not as an answer?

Comment: Because I don't have any references to back it up.